# htaccess - hide file extension and keep only value of a variable

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, litespeed

original url - `example.com/art.php?a=lorem`
want to be visible as - `example.com/art/lorem`
`litespeed` server - htaccess is enabled

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^art/(.*)$ /art.php?a=$1 [L]
```

doesn't work
url is still - `example.com/art.php?a=lorem`
pls help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have a rewrite rule to rewrite `example.com/art/lorem` but you are missing a redirect rule to redirect `example.com/art.php?a=lorem` to `example.com/art/lorem`.

You may use:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+art\.php\?a=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /art/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^art/([\w-]+)/?$ art.php?a=$1 [L,QSA]
```

`THE_REQUEST` variable represents original request received by Apache from your browser and it doesn't get overwritten after execution of other rewrite directives. Example value of this variable is `GET /index.php?id=123 HTTP/1.1`

**References:**

- [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)
- [Apache mod_rewrite Technical Details](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/tech.html)
- [Apache mod_rewrite In-Depth Details](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-deeper-look-at-mod_rewrite-for-apache--net-6708)
- [.htaccess tips and tricks](http://corz.org/server/tricks/htaccess2.php)

Comment: it works, thanks a lot, especially for your explanation. I'm totally confused about all regarding `.htaccess`  and can't find any reference for beginners. BTW see this one line but similar solution - `https://css-tricks.com/snippets/htaccess/remove-file-extention-from-urls/`

Comment: I have added bunch of reference links in my answer.